# how to implement lazy loading in a table / datatable?

Tags: php, datatables, lazy-loading

I just want to load data to a table but I have over 600k records so it is taking a lot of time to load this to a table. Currently I'm using datatable like this:

```
$('#datatablesContacts').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "scrollX": true,
             "ajax": 'jsphp/servergetdata.php'

  });
```

But still it's taking a lot of time like it freezes the page. So my question now is how to implement lazy loading in a table / datatable? Or is there any library that I can use to implement lazy loading? I'm using PHP as backend script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use server-side script that will paginate results and enable [server-side processing mode](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Processing-modes) with [`serverSide: true`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide).

With PHP you can use `ssp.class.php` that is available in `/examples/server_side/scripts` folder when you [download DataTables library](https://datatables.net/download/download).

There is also a sample script `server_processing.php` in `/examples/server_side/scripts` folder that shows how to use it.